# .jar file doens't open on double click but opens in the command prompt

Tags: java, jar, command-prompt, executable-jar

Here's the story:

I wrote a program yesterday and exported it to a jar file. I then tried to open it by double clicking it, and nothing happened. After a bit of research, I made sure that my jre was up to date (it is). I associated javaw.exe with jar files by right clicking the file and navigating to javaw.

The funny thing is that the file works in command prompt, meaning I can execute it there, but nothing happens on a double click on the desktop. So I thought it might be, because the program doesn't have a GUI or anything, meaning it has no pop up window. It's just text. So I wrote a tiny program that uses JOptionPane to display "Hello." That .jar also works if opened through the command prompt, but still doesn't open on a double click.

Does anyone know why?

If it helps, here's the second program code, which, as I mentioned, also doesn't work on a double click:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work is that you need to use -jar argument to start a .jar file with javaw. See here: http://www.wikihow.com/Run-a-.Jar-Java-File

When you simply associate file extension .jar with javaw.exe, the -jar argument is missing. As far as I know it is not easy to let it use -jar, because this option is not present in Windows GUI, but it can be done with some smart Windows registry editing tool. Read this question for more information: https://superuser.com/questions/136133/how-do-i-set-advanced-file-associations-in-windows-7

**update:**
Create a helper .bat file contining `javaw.exe -jar "%1" %*` and associate .jar extension with this bat file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll read through the links for sure. Does that means that it's nothing wrong with the file, but more with how my system is handling it?

Comment: If it can be started from the command line, the jar file is fine.